# I have no idea why I keep getting null object error upon httprequest in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm a newbie to react-native.
I have this odd issue concerning User model I've defined below.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

class User extends Sequelize.Model {
   static init(sequelize) {

   return super.init(
   {
      id: {
         type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
         autoIncrement: true,
         allowNull: false,
         primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
         type: Sequelize.STRING,
         allowNull: false,
      },
      password: {
         type: Sequelize.STRING,
         allowNull: false,
      },
      phone_number: {
         type: Sequelize.STRING,
         allowNull: false,
      }
      },
      { 
         sequelize,
         timestamps: false, 
         modelName: 'User',
         tableName: 'user'
      }
      );
   }

   static associate(db){
      db.User.hasMany(db.Profile, {foreignkey : 'user_Id', sourceKey: 'id', onDelete: 'cascade', onUpdate: 'cascade'});
   }
};

module.exports = User;
```

When I call signup API with the User model, I keep getting this null error.
The following is the signup API that I'm having a problem with.

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const signup = (req, res, next) => {
    // checks if email already exists
    console.log(req.body.phone_number)
    User.findOne({ where : {
        phone_number:req.body.phone_number 
    }})
    .then(dbUser => {
        console.log("Arrived!!");
```

I think there shouldn't be nothing wrong with the above code, and I can see the phone_number is correctly passed. However, here is the output.

01000000000 (Just a dummy variable used for phone number)
error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

I don't get why it keeps complaining an object being null.
Which object is it referring to, and how can I fix this?

Thanks a log in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize'
import sequelize from '../utils/database.js';

class User extends Sequelize.Model {};
User.init(
{
id: {
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
autoIncrement: true,
allowNull: false,
primaryKey: true,
},
name: {
type: Sequelize.STRING,
allowNull: false,
},
password: {
type: Sequelize.STRING,
allowNull: false,
},
phone_number: {
type: Sequelize.STRING,
allowNull: false,
}
},
{
sequelize,
timestamps: false,
modelName: 'User',
tableName: 'user'
}
);

export default User;
```

try using this way of defining Model, It works for me!!